# Import Apple Development Teams into Xamarin Studio on Mac without fastlane?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xcode8, xamarin-studio, provisioning-profile

Is it possible to import Apple Development Teams into Xamarin Studio on Mac without installing **fastlane**?

I'm comfortable with letting Xcode manage my Apple ID, passwords, certificates, provisioning profiles. I would like to avoid bringing in a third-party tool like *fastlane* into this process (seems to me quite insecure to enter my AppleID & password in any tools outside Apple's ecosystem)

UPDATE:

Adding a screenshot to explain where are the Development Teams missing in Xamarin Studio.

[image: Development Teams missing]

Comment: I will first say that fastlane is used actively by Wikipedia, Firefox, Soundcloud, to name a few so it is fairly trustworthy. But, regarding your question, what problem are you having? What do you mean by **Apple Development Teams**? When you open a Xamarin.iOS project in Xamarin Studio, you should usually see your provisioning profile within the Xamarin.iOS project's properties. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have added a screenshot to explain where are the Development teams missing. BTW I had some error messages during installing *fastlane* and that's one of the reasons why I was questioning it's credibility; the second was I don't know why isn't is using Apple Keychain. But okay, Wikipedia and Firefox are rock solid references so I will give it another try!

Comment: I got it working for the most part but ran into errors on certain things. I might be able to help, though I have only messed around with it for a couple days. One thing I know that they have struggled with is getting the private keys out of the Mac Keychain and/or the Apple Developer site, which is why they suggest you delete your current certs and allow fastlane to generate new ones. I have found blog posts showing how you can do it with certificates you already created but never got it working myself.

Answer (score 0):

So I have never actually tried use Xamarin Studio to do all of that stuff for me, I did not even know it was able to do all of that. I guess I did it the manual way which might work better for you.

If you are trying to enable push notifications I would highly suggest following [Xamarin's Guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote_notifications_in_ios/) which walks you through manually creating an APNS certificate (which I think it what Xamarin Studio is trying to do for you by using fastlane).

As far as the Entitlements.plist file, my app uses remote Push Notifications and does not specify anything special in its Entitlements.plist file, so that part may not even be necessary for you unless there is a specific reason to do it.

My app adds the following to it's Info.plist file though:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

That along with enabling Push Notifications in the app's App Id on the Apple Developer site, associating the App Id with an APNS certificate, and then regenerating your Provisioning Profiles should be more or less all you need to do (other than adding actual code).

Comment: I did some apps with push notifications in Xcode and I never tried not to enable 'Push notifications' in the Entitlements.list :) Okay, I will try it, thanks! Although, I would be happy to just 'make it work', because the next thing I'm going to need is 'In App Purchases' and that's also a part of the entitlement list. This should work out of the box I guess..

Comment: @adamsfamily Definitely let me know if you run into any issues. For me, the certificate creation was fairly straightforward compared to the coding. Incase you are interested, the **fastlane pem** tool is what is used to create APNS certificates but it does not actually upload it to the Apple server like other fastlane tools can do for your distribution certificate.